# Does it matter how a war file is named?

Tags: java, maven, war, archive, application-server

Is it important how a war is called? Does it have any effect on whether it will work correctly? Let's say you're building a war with maven, naming it in one way and then manually rename it to some other name before deploying it somewhere on a server and running it, would it have any effect on working? Like deploy issues, etc?

Let's say with the maven war plugin you set it to generate *something.war* and later rename it to *newfilename.war* before deploying. What is your experience/knowledge there?

Comment: As long as you point to the correct file and don't mess about with the POM, no problems. My data server servlet was in Tomcat and I think my war file name didn't really matter much as long as I selected the correct file before deploying it on Tomcat localhost. You must not fiddle with .war extension though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name might matter depending on the servlet container: tomcat uses the name of the war file without the .war extension as the context path. This can be adjusted though using container-specific configuration files inside the .war file.

Obviously it would also matter in that case when you're trying to access it.

Comment: So you might get an error and it might not get deployed if you renamed it? That's with Tomcat? Any experience with JBoss on that?

Comment: You won't get an error, it will simply look at the name and deploy it. In your example, it would deploy it with a context path /newfilename, not /something. JBoss is very similar to tomcat (older versions were based on it).